# dealing with cpu bound ops

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We know Node.JS works in a async single-thread fashion.
I've worked with MongoDB for months now, and honestly I'm finding the query language not so powerful, to be nice. The aggregation framework brought important features, but SQL features like inner queries are very far (note I'm not talking about massive joins).
So I've found myself multiple times to supply this lack with awful result-sets traversing (foreach) in order to shape the results I want.

Obviously it's not doable with large datasets. In Node.JS environment those things are a real disaster since I block the entire server to serve a single request.

How do you deal with these kinds of cpu-bound task?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the whole Node.js architecuture is based on the single threaded event loop so any CPU-bound function will block entire server till the function will finish its operation.

Among the possible workarounds could be

- dividing you service into several parallel node.js applicaitons;
- using multiple cores with parallel workers executing on different cores.

Take look at this article: [Why you should use Node.js for CPU-bound tasks](http://Why%20you%20should%20use%20Node.js%20for%20CPU-bound%20tasks).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you don't rebuild the results. You design a query that MongoDB can handle in order to get the results you want... it'd probably be better to open a question related to that particular issue as there may be something you're missing.

---

But let's say you actually have found an exception (which is unlikely) and you need to build a large set of data that bottlenecks. There's a good chance this operation can be optimized so again...you should open a question related to this issue to see what improvements can be made.

---

Lets say you are indeed a very rare exception and all the above won't work for you. You have several (more complex) options to choose from:

1. [Clusters](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) or [ChildProcess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) - Allow you to stand alone processes as a form of concurrency.
2. [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) - Messaging Queues are another tool to allow for concurrency, note there are other libraries available
3. [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) or [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/) - Migrate back to SQL if you're better with it. Write a script that reads from MongoDB and performs INSERTs into your new database then write the query you want

---

Please note options 1 & 2 above also allow you to interface with other languages that would be better suited at handling large sets of data.

Comment: This is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474513/real-virtual-field-inherited-fields. The final aim (not explained in the question) is to get all the docs related to a each tag. Basically an SQL `GROUP BY`, with the exception that docBs inherits the tags from the referred docA. I solved with an insane async.series with 3 steps and 3 nested foreach in the final step